# IntelliJ gradle project doesn't copy resources outside resources folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I've encountered the following problem:

I started a new gradle project in IntelliJ. By default it consists of a main folder with java sources and resources.If I keep my resources in the resources folder everything is fine. However that is not what I want. I want to be able to place some resources in java packages.

I made a small project to demonstrate my issue.

[image: project overview]

As you can see the test.fxml gets copied when the project is build, but the one in the 'Main' package isn't. I've looked for some time now, but I am missing some crucial information.

Does IntelliJ use gradle tasks to build the project when it gets built from inside the IDE? If not where can I tell IntelliJ to copy also my resources from the java packages?

I already added the "*.fxml" to my Settings->Compiler->Resource patterns

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the **test.fxml** file has to be in the same folder as the Main.class file in the build directory. So you would have to follow the exact same path structure in your **src** and your **ressources** folder.

Comment: I don't think you understood my issue here. My problem is that I don't want to use the rescources folder. It is working ok if i use it. For practical reasons I don't want to use it. Also I noticed that when i create a 'java project' instead of a 'gradle project' it also is working like expected.

Comment: Yeah the resource pattern only works for resource labeled folders unfortunately... I haven't found any workaround yet...